# SendKeys(Keys.COMMAND+"a") is inserting a symbol in text field

Tags: sendkeys, appium-ios

Node version - 8.9.1

Appium version - 1.7.2

I am trying to clear an already existing text in a login field, however the solution that is provided on various forums doesn't seem to solve my problem.

While I am using the below code:

driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("oobe-join-input-email").sendKeys(Keys.COMMAND+"a", Keys.BACK_SPACE);
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("oobe-join-input-email").sendKeys("sdasdasdadasd");

is inserting a camera like a symbol and amending the existing text instead of selecting all and deleting the text.

See attached screenshot.

driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("oobe-join-input-email").sendKeys("");
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("oobe-join-input-email").clear();
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("oobe-join-input-email").sendKeys("sdasdasdadasd")

I tried the above alternative solution as well but it doesn't seem to work for me.
Tried the below suggestion as well. But this doesn't seem to work as well.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

**screenshot of what I get**

[image: screenshot of what I get]

Comment: hi, Use long press on that element and you get list of menus. In that, Selectall and cut/delete

Comment: @Nihal Alfred : By any chance have you solved this. I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue so I tried following code & it works for me

```
        IOSElement email = driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("oobe-join-input-email");
        String text = email.getText();
        int maxChars = text.length();
        for(int i =0;i < maxChars;i++) {
        email.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
        }
```

Comment: This works but the speed is very slow . Like around 3 to 4 seconds for each backspace . I am doing this on iPhone . By any chance do you have the solution for the speed as well.